# Lendo no Delphi XML gerado no Excel

Tags: delphi, xml

Estou gerando um XML pelo próprio Excel (arquivo do tipo Planilha XML 2003).

O arquivo gerado tem o seguinte padrão de dados XML:

```
<Row>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Williams</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Datass:Type="Number">10644</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">UK</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Qtr 2</Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

Criando um projeto no Delphi, utilizando um DataSet e um DataSource, e fazendo a configuração padrão, o Delphi não consegue ler os campos deste XML, como ocorre quando temos um arquivo no padrão abaixo. O que fazer para converter a planilha Excel em um padrão XML que o Delphi entenda, ou então como interpretar este padrão de XML?

```
<ROW NOME="PAMELA" DT_NASCIMENTO="19521002" DT_CADASTRO="20031020" TELEFONE="2548874"
CELULAR="93712225" EMAIL="pamela@email.com"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Este modelo referido

```
<ROW NOME="PAMELA" DT_NASCIMENTO="19521002" DT_CADASTRO="20031020" TELEFONE="2548874"
CELULAR="93712225" EMAIL="pamela@email.com"/>
```

é o Schema de dados do ClientDataSet e difere do modelo citado acima, que vem do Excel.

Para fazer a leitura do Schema do Excel, você deve utilizar um `XMLDocument`  e não o `TClientDataSet`

Como no seguinte exemplo:

```
var
  XMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
  MainNode, RowNode: TXMLNode;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  XMLDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    XMLDocument.FileName := 'C:\Caminho\Para\Seu\Arquivo.xml';
    XMLDocument.Active := True;

    MainNode := XMLDocument.DocumentElement;

    for I := 0 to MainNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      RowNode := MainNode.ChildNodes[I];

      for J := 0 to RowNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
      begin
        //Cada item aqui é uma célula e vc pode obter o valor
      end;
    end;

    XMLDocument.Active := False;
  finally
    XMLDocument := nil; //Ele é uma interface e é liberado automaticamente
  end;
```

Comment: Incompatible types: 'TXMLDocument' and 'IXMLNode'

Comment: Isso aparece quando compilada a linha MainNode... e RowNode. Deixei o código exatamente como você sugeriu, só alterei o endereço do XML e adicionei o XMLDocumet da aba Internet.

Comment: @user3771516 Eu corrigi o exemplo. O tipo dos nodes é TXMLNode ou IXMLNode. Eu estou sem o Deplhi aqui para testar o exemplo. Qualquer outro erro, me fale que eu revejo.

Comment: Rodou com o tipo IXMLNode. Agora tem outro erro que ocorre quando executa a linha do primeiro For. Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 000000. Nota: O endereço do xml está certo, e é no padrão que coloquei na postagem inicial. Será que tem algo de diferente no cabeçalho do arquivo?

Comment: @user3771516 aparentemente o delphi está liberando o XMLDocument antes da hora por ele não ser mais utilizado diretamente. Vou alterar agora para utilizar IXMLDocument e desabilitá-lo antes do finally

Comment: Mesma falha do inicio. Incompatible types: 'TXMLDocument' and 'IXMLNode'. Se tiver mais alguma sugestão, agradeço. Para quebrar um galho, estou utilizando o Excel + VBA para montar as telas que estou precisando.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o utilitário [XMLMapper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_XMLMapper) para [mapear os dados](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37321) do arquivo XML para um TClientDataset. A partir daí você poderá importar os dados no TClientDataset e manipular.

Comment: Bom dia..@EMBarbosa.. Estou temdo problema em gerar o arquivo .xtr e o .xml pelo delphi TOKYO... Ao gerar os arquivos e ligar no CLIENTDATASET o mesmo da o seguinte  erro..:  XML PARSE ERROR Reason: O sistema não pode localizar o objeto especificado. . E pelo DELPHI 7 eu gero e utilizo no clientDataSet sem problema.. Sabe me informar qual a diferença entre o XMLMAPPER do delphi 7 e o TOKYO??

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza até onde eu sei, nenhuma diferença que pudesse causar esse tipo de erro. Me parece mais que o XMLMapper está apenas retornando um erro reportado pelo Windows. Como se o caminho do arquivo que você especificou não existisse.

Comment: .Cara acabei de descobrir o porque do erro.  no delphi 7 uso o XMLTransform e funciona beleza.. No delphi TOKYO fui usar o mesmo componente ai aparece essa mensagem.. Na net vi um artigo que o cara usa o XMLTransformProvider ai  FUNCIONA perfeitamente.. Cara ..Obrigado pela atenção. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer o delphi ler corretamente o xml gerado pelo Excel:

```
vXMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(self);
vXMLDoc.LoadFromFile('Exemplo.xml');

J := vXMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count;
Memo1.Clear;

for K := 0 to j -1 do
begin
  NodeRec := vXMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[K];  
  Memo1.Lines.Add(NodeRec.ChildNodes[0].text + ' -' + 
  NodeRec.ChildNodes[1].text  + '-' 
  + NodeRec.ChildNodes[2].text+ ' -' + NodeRec.ChildNodes[3].text);     
end;
```